# How to show that $ C := A^3-3A^2+2A = 0$?

Tags: matrices, spectral-theory, diagonalization

> Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 2  \end{pmatrix}$$
> Let $C:= A^3-3A^2+2A $.
> Show that $C=0$.

I know that $A$ is diagonalisable with $\operatorname{spec}(A)=\{0,1,2\}$.
I have no clue how to approach that problem. Any advice?

Comment: It is not complicate to find $A^3$ nor $A^2$...

Comment: A direct computation is enough

Comment: Check if $0,1,2$ are roots of $x^3+3x^2+2x$. Did you mean $0,-1,-2$? Or perhaps $A^3-3A^2+2A$?

Comment: I used $\textbf{GeoGebra}$, and did not found that $C=0$...

Comment: Is there another way? Could I show it formally without calculation?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak That is the exercise. So, there is a mistake? I will just calculate it and see what the result really is.

Comment: Even with Cayley–Hamilton theorem, you still need to calculate a determinant.

Comment: Apply *Hamilton-Cayley*, once you've found the correct eigenvalues.

Comment: @Bernard The correct eigenvalues are as I mentioned 0,1,2 of A  and I will try.

Comment: @Bernard No need for the eigenvalues, as they are usually found by taking roots of the characteristic polynomial. Cayley-Hamilton is already enough then.

Comment: If they're correct, $A^3+3A^3+2A$ is not $0$.

Comment: Then the exercise is mistaken, Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You have a typo.Note that $С=A^3-3A^2+2A=A(A-I)(A-2I)$. Characteristic polynomial is $P(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)$.

Comment: @WhatsUp: I've checked the eigenvalues, and they're correct, so the question is erroneous.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, there has to be a mistake. I think $C:=A^3-3A^2+2A$ is correct as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: To @Logik: I used $\textbf{GeoGebra}$ again, but for $C=A^3 - 3A^2+2A$, now I got $C=0$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I think is just a typo in the exercise. I will update the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:** you can solve it by direct computation:

$$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ -1 & 3 & 2  \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$A^3 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 7 & 2 \\ 0 & 8 & 0 \\ -1 & 7 & 2  \end{pmatrix}.$$

You can actually argue that

$$A^n = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k & 2 \\ 0 & 2^n & 0 \\ -1 & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k & 2  \end{pmatrix}.$$

Thus if you sum up you easily see that $C\neq 0$.

**Method 2:** you can use Cayley-Hamilton theorem for these kinds of problems
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem.

By this theorem you would get that

$$A^3-3A^2+2A=0,$$

which is actually verifiable by direct computation. **Conversely**, always by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, if you knew the eigenvalues you could have just plugged them in $\lambda^3+3\lambda^2+2\lambda=0$ and verified that this equation is not satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I also added the part with Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic equation of $A$ is $\det|A-\lambda I|=0$ it works tp $\lambda^3-3\lambda^2+2\lambda$ and according Caley-Hamilton theorem.: Every masytric satsfioes its own characteristic polynomial. So we have $$A^3-2A^2+2A=0~~~~(1)$$

Other methodd every $3\times 3$ matrix satisfies a monic ploynomial which is given by
$$A^2-(a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33})A^2+(m_{11}+m_{22}+m_{33})A-\det|A|I=0~~~~(2)$$ Here $a_{kk}$ are diagonal elements and $m_{kk}$ are the minors of diagonal element. Notice that $\det|A|=0$, so the $I$ term is missing in (1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. Note that $С=A^3-3A^2+2A=A(A-I)(A-2I)$. Characteristic polynomial is $P(\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)$. Due  Hamilton-Cayley theorem $C=0$.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the typo!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to obtain the value of $p(A)$, where $p(X)= X^3+3X^2+2X$, using *Hamilton-Cayley*:

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\:\chi_A=X(X-1)(X-2)=X^3-3^2+2X$, and we have
$p(X)=\chi_A(X)-6X^2$, so
$$p(A)=\chi_A(A)-6A^2=-6A^2$$
so you have only one matrix multiplication to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!